# How to stop postback when calling usercontrol

Tags: asp.net-ajax, user-controls, postback, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopupExtender control and a panel which contains a iframe. The ModalPopupExtender's TargetControlID property is set to a html button control named btnFind.

When I click to find button, the panel with its iframe control shows as a modal popup.

This is work fine,but then I decided to take these control to an usercontrol and use this simplier and many times. I made it, and it works, but when I call usercontrol to open modal popup, my Main page is postbacking. I couldn't stop it. My user control's syntax is below. Can anyone give me some advices to stop the postback?

```
<PBG:Modal ID="mdlFind" runat="server" Height="460" Width="840" TargetControlId="btnFind" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `runat="server"`

Comment: I removed it but it didn't work. Usercontrols must has this property.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Use Updatepanel(ajax panel for asp.net) to avoid postback.
```